# Display a waveform like Audacity in Python

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, waveform, audacity

Audacity can display waveform of millions of points very easily and zoom in and out smoothly. I'm trying to do the same in Python but I didn't find anything that can display more than 5 millions of points for the moment.

Matplotlib doesn't seem to be effective enough to display that much data. I'm trying to do it with Bokeh but it suffers of the same problem (maybe I'm using it wrongly). Finally, Vaex seems not to work because it doesn't show me anything.

For the moment, my display function looks like this and the input is a 2D-numpy array with x coordinate on the first row and y on the second :

```
def display(data):
    p = figure(plot_width=1250, plot_height=550) 

    p.line(data[0], data[1])

    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ("X", "@x"),
        ("Y", "@y"),
    ])

    p.add_tools(hover)

    show(p)
```

Comment: With that amount of data, where each pixel will usually contain multiple items, you probably want to use `datashader` _with_ Bokeh. But you will not be able to generate static plots - you will have to use Bokeh server.